# Sort array by natural order without maintaining index numbers

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am sorting `$myarray` with `natsort($myarray)`. The array is sorted and the index numbers are maintained as you can see below.

**Before sort**

```
Array ( [0] => 2 C [1] => 3 A [2] => 1 B )
```

**After sort**

```
Array ( [2] => 1 B [0] => 2 C [1] => 3 A )
```

Is it possible to sort without maintaining the index numbers?
I expected an array like this after I sort:

**Expected result**

```
Array ( [0] => 1 B [1] => 2 C [2] => 3 A )
```

Comment: simply use array_values and a sort function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `nasort` and  `array_values` function.

> The `natsort()` function sorts an array by using a "natural order"
>   algorithm. The values keep their original keys.

Because the `nasort` keeps the key, you need to use the `array_values`, its makes a new array with relative index.

**Process**

```
$arr = array('0' => '2 C', '1' => '3 A', '2' => '1 B'); 
natsort($arr);
$arr = array_values($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

**Rresult**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 B
    [1] => 2 C
    [2] => 3 A
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php
$your_array = array('2 C', '3 A', '1 B'); 
natsort($your_array);
$your_array = array_values($your_array);
print_r($your_array);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the array into new variables after fetching the values only like so..$sorted_new_array = array_values($your_sorted_array);

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reset keys.

OR

[sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Code using both the functions and creating same output:

```
<?php
$arr = array ('2 C', '3 A', '1 B');
$sorted = array_values($arr);
echo '<pre>';print_r($sorted);echo '</pre>';

sort($arr);
echo '<pre>';print_r($arr);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2 C
    [1] => 3 A
    [2] => 1 B
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1 B
    [1] => 2 C
    [2] => 3 A
)
```

Comment: You have changed the values of array

Answer (score 1):

You can do a one-liner using normal sort with the natural sort option:

```
sort($array,SORT_NATURAL);
```

Example:

```
$fruits = array("lemon3", "lemon2", "orange2","orange10", "banana4", "apple9");
sort($fruits,SORT_NATURAL);
print_r($fruits);
```

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => apple9
>       [1] => banana4
>       [2] => lemon2
>       [3] => lemon3
>       [4] => orange2
>       [5] => orange10
>   )

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$arr = array ('2C', '3A', '1B');
//predefined function
uasort($arr,'sortArray');

function sortArray($indexOne, $indexTwo)
{
    if($indexOne < $indexTwo)

        return -1; 

    if($indexOne > $indexTwo)

        return 1;

    if($indexOne == $indexTwo)

        return 0;
}

$getResult = array_values($arr);
print_r($getResult);
?>
```

Comment: This does not sort the array

Comment: <?php
$arr = array ('2C', '3A', '1B');
//predefined function
uasort($arr,'sortArray');

function sortArray($indexOne, $indexTwo)
{
    if($indexOne < $indexTwo)

        return -1; 

    if($indexOne > $indexTwo)

        return 1;

    if($indexOne == $indexTwo)

        return 0;
}

$getResult = array_values($arr);
print_r($getResult); check this code